# How to scrape text that only unlocks after clicking "more" button

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape a review from the trip advisor website. I succeed in scraping the reviews, but some reviews are long and are partially shown, until you click the "more" button.

This is the link of the website :
https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Hotel_Review-g190479-d3587956-Reviews-The_Thief-Oslo_Eastern_Norway.html#REVIEWS

This is the source code of the "more" button:

```
<span class= soup.findAll(attrs={"class": "entry"}):
    review =  item.text.replace(',', '').replace('\n', ' ').encode('utf-8').strip()
```

This is how i grab the reviews from the page

```
for item in soup.findAll(attrs={"class": "entry"}):
    review =  item.text.replace(',', '').replace('\n', ' ').encode('utf-8').strip()
```

How do i manage to scrape all the reviews after the more button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try loading the page in Selenium. This would allow you to interact with javascript. I haven't tried it with BeautifulSoup, but I think it would look something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver  
import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox() #Or any other driver you want 
browser.get('https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Hotel_Review-g190479-d3587956-Reviews-The_Thief-Oslo_Eastern_Norway.html#REVIEWS')  
next_btn = browser.find_element_by_xpath('PATH_FOR_NEXT_LINK_ELEMENT')
next_btn.click()
html_source = browser.page_source  
browser.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html_source)  
review = soup("YOUR_SCRAPING_LOGIC")
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

When you click the `More` link, JavaScript code will run in the browser to get data or jump to another link, `requests` will return the html code, it can not handle the JavaScript.